# Getting the Auth Token for the secondary Id from Google chrome extension using OAuth 2.0 & Client ID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am fairly new to developing chrome extensions, more specifically to the user authentication part in chrome extensions. I am following [User Identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) example from Google Developer docs.

The example works perfectly fine. I was able to generate the client id for the chrome app, add the scope for API's in my case Gmail API. And finally get the Auth Token by adding the `identity`permission in `manifest.json` as follows

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "MY CLIENT ID",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
    ]
  }
```

And my app.js is a content_script which has the following code.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
    /* With which I can use xhr requests to get data from Gmail API */
      console.log('Access Token : '+token);
});
```

Now this token that I get gives me the result for the user with which I have logged into chrome. Meaning Let's say I have a UserA with email address user_a@gmail.com and I have used this log into the chrome browser.

**Question**

How do I get the associated accounts or the secondary accounts? For instance, let's say a UserB logs into Gmail from the chrome browser. Is it possible to access the Gmail API for that particular user who is currently logged in?

I have tried a couple of things here.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, 
          function(authResult){//do something});
```

In the above scenario, the client id and scopes are fetched from the `manifest.json` using `chrome.runtime.getManifest();`.

- This method uses the client.js from google api's and makes use of gapi variable.
- In this case, I get the access token for the user whom I generated the client id, not even the chrome application user.
- Furthermore, When I open an incognito mode and access this plugin, still I get the same user's access token.

**Additional Note**

I tried the same `gapi.auth.authorize()` using a Web OAuth 2 Client Id. It works perfectly fine. I mean whenever this authorize is executed it fetches the current logged in user's data or it asks for a login where the user can log in and authenticate. How do I achieve the same thing in chrome extension? Kindly let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: I've been trying to find an answer to this myself.  The lack of help here is discouraging.  Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getAuthToken), it looks like you can specify the account ID, but the question is how to get that account ID.  There is the [getAccounts Method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getAccounts), but it is in dev channel, so not of much help.  :(

Comment: I have been DESPERATELY trying to find an answer to this.  I've tried many many methods.  launchWebAuthFlow(), gapi, chrome.identity, xhr requests, etc.  _NOTHING_ has worked.   The documentation is terrible and there is a serious lack of info on the Internet about this.  If ANYONE has any info on this, PRETTY PRETTY PLEASE share!!!

Comment: @Morfie : Any luck so far? I have opened a bounty for the same. Let's see if we can get some pointers.

Comment: Actually, yes. Let me post some updates. I can't do it this second (in the middle of fixing something, but I'll add a reminder to update it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.streak.com/2014/10/how-to-use-gmail-api-in-chrome-extension.html

is the complete solution which I have recently implemented on background page to work with Gmail API.

The content script is calling popup window to authorize using generated URL and simple server endpoint to store the refresh token.

```
$.oauthpopup = function (options) {
options.windowName = options.windowName || 'ConnectWithOAuth'; // should not include space for IE

var left = (screen.width / 2) - (800 / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (500 / 1.4);

options.windowOptions = options.windowOptions || 'location=0,status=0,width=800,height=500,left=' + left + ',top=' + top;
options.callback = options.callback || function () {
    window.location.reload();
};
var that = this;

debug('oauthpopup open separate _oauthWindow');
that._oauthWindow = window.open(options.path, options.windowName, options.windowOptions);
};

$.oauthpopup({
            path: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' +
            'access_type=offline' +
            '&approval_prompt=force' +
            '&client_id=' + clientID +
            '&redirect_uri=' + callBackUrl +
            '&response_type=code' +
            '&scope=https://mail.google.com/ email profile' +
            '&state=' + login.timyoUUID +
            '&user_id=' + login.user_email,
            callback: function () {
                // do callback stuff
            },
        });
```

callBackUrl is used to store refresh token on the server.

Here is the example how I set access token for every request to gapi

```
export function setTokenForGAPI(accessToken) {
return getGAPIClient()
    .then(() => {
        const isSameToken = (currentAccessToken === accessToken);
        const noToken = ((accessToken === undefined) || (accessToken === ''));
        if (isSameToken || noToken) return;

        gapi.auth.setToken({
            access_token: accessToken,
        });

        currentAccessToken = accessToken;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log('error in setTokenForGAPI', e);
    });
}
export function getEmailsByThreadIds(accessToken, ids) {
    return setTokenForGAPI(accessToken)
        .then(groupedThreadDetailsRequests(ids))
        .then(processEmailDetailsResponse);
}
```

Comment: I am already doing this process. The issue that i am having is getting is I am able to get OAuth token for User A who is signed into Chrome. I would like to get the Oauth token for User B who is signed in via gmail .

Comment: @Sumuga i've done auth for both users from content script on gmail side
After receiving refresh token and getting access token I set it in gapi. I've provided the code snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, ***this is not possible using supported APIs*** in Google Chrome stable (Version 63). However, in the Dev channel and most likely with a future release, the following will be possible:

```
chrome.identity.getAccounts(function(accounts) {
    // accounts is a list of accounts.
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true, 'account': accounts[0] }, function(token) {
        /* With which i can use xhr requests to get data from gmail api */
          console.log('Access Token : '+token);
    });
});
```

See [the documentation for `getAccounts()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAccounts).

---

**EDIT**: Something that *might* work in the meantime is registering for [the `onSigninChanged` event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#event-onSignInChanged).

Answer (score 2):

How I ended up handling is was this (summary):

1. In the page layer, on load, I send a message down the stack to the background layer.
2. I used launchWebAuthFlow() to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth to get the access_token for the account.
3. I made an AJAX call to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token using the access_token to get a refresh token.

When a user changes which account they are using via the avatar button on the top-right, this process is triggered again, as it is initiated by onLoad for the page layer of the extension.

The things left out the description above are caching and error handling, which are super-important.